# IllegalArgumentException when setting Image in Jigloo

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I am trying to make GUIs in SWT using Jigloo and when I want to set images to Labels or Buttons, I can see them in the preview pane. However, when i compile and run it, it throws

```
SWTResourceManager.getImage: Error getting image img/game/front/test.png, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument cannot be null
```

The code it generates looks like this:

```
opIcon = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
FormData opIconLData = new FormData();
opIconLData.width = 64;
opIconLData.height = 64;
opIconLData.left =  new FormAttachment(0, 1000, 12);
opIconLData.top =  new FormAttachment(0, 1000, 12);
opIcon.setLayoutData(opIconLData);
opIcon.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("img/game/front/test.png"));
```

The SWTResourceManager class seems to be largely undocumented so I'm kinda lost here. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method requires an absolute path,

```
SWTResourceManager.getImage("/home/img/game/front/test.png");
```